# Handling images in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a Drupal website. I want users to create pages that sometime has images in it. Is there a module that:

- can integrate with the ck editor
- lets the user upload images
- lets the user browse uploaded images and select and include them in the page they create?

Thanks

-Vivek

Answer (score 1):

By far the best way is Imagefield, Imagecache and optionally Insert and Image Resize Filter modules.

Answer (score 0):

There are literally dozens of modules offering this functionality in one way or the other, often in various combination with other modules, so it is hard to give a straight 'use this' answer, but one of the most commonly used modules for this is probably the [IMCE module](http://drupal.org/project/imce).

To get an overview of the alternatives, you could start with this [Comparison of Image-handling modules](http://drupal.org/node/316884) and the links provided there.

Comment: @henrijs: I did not say that IMCE is cool/modern etc., just that it is commonly used in the requested scenario. I prefer Imagefield/Imagecache based solutions personally as well, but the 'user browses and selects existing images' as well as the 'ck editor integration' requests are difficult to fullfill with those.